# Как подписать POST/GET запросы на сервер с приложения андроид?

Tags: android, post, get

В общем вопрос в следующем как возможно подписать запросы с приложения которые сохраняют что-то в бд на сервере. Чтобы кто угодно не мог слать запросы ко мне на сервер и сохранять что либо в бд. Мб как то проверять сами запросы. Может быть от гугла какое то решение есть. Посоветуйте что то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов много. Можете отправлять токены. Все зависит от задач. Если у вас разные пользователи с разными правами:

1. Пользователь вводит логин и пароль. Все это отправляется на сервер. Он в свою очередь проверяет данные. Потом создает токен для этого пользователя, записывает его в бд и возвращает в ответе.
2. Клиент(ваше приложение) сохраняет этот токен у себя. И при обращении на сервер подставляет этот токен в запрос.
3. Сервер при любом запросе проверяет отправленный токен.

Это минимум, для работы. Почитайте про авторизацию с помощью токенов.

Comment: Вариант хороший а если нет авторизации в приложении?

Comment: У вас будет один токен. Пропускаете пункт 1.

Comment: Допустим юзер регистрируется в приложении через еmail, и его email уже шлется на сервер, т.е. в этот момент надо чтоб сервер как то определял что это юзер зарегестрировался именно с приложения а не какой то там чел просто отправил запрос на сервер и добавил юзера или еще что то в бд.

Comment: Отправляете токен, проверяете на сервере.

Comment: Мысль понял можно какой то алгоритм который генерит число и контрольную сумму проверяет, слать это число или хеш, и проверять так же на сервере, ключ только у меня будет и в приложении. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: По сути ваше приложение могут(если захотят) распоковать и достать токен. Поэтому нужно чаще менять токен.

Comment: Неужели у гугла никаких решений нет?

Comment: Решений чего? Авторизации? Вот почитайте:https://m.habr.com/ru/company/dataart/blog/262817/